# Executor service shutdownNow , how it works

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

According to doc for method `shutdownNow` (ExecutorService)

```
There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop
      processing actively executing tasks.  For example, typical
      implementations will cancel via {@link Thread#interrupt}, so any
      task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate
```

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
            final Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setDaemon(false);
            return thread;
        });
        service.submit(() -> {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Done: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            }
        });
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        service.shutdownNow();
    }
```

This is the output:

```
Done: false
Done: false
```

After two loops its stop to execute.
How does shutdownNow interrupt my job , I just have infinite loop , there is no check for `Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted();`

In my mind, `shutdownNow` only call interrupt method of working thread

Comment: How about calling `cancel` on the `Future` that is returned by `submit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` checks `.isInterrupted()` and throws an `InterruptedException` if it's interrupted. Your lambda implicitly `throws InterruptedException`, and so it never reaches your `System.out.println` when the executor is shutdown. You can browse the [source for `ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#l1421) to see how this happens.

Answer (score 0):

That is internal mechanism, but if you add try nad catch like below you will get InterruptedException thrown from sleep method (cause thread is already interrupted by shutdown method) so shutdown method really changes the thread state.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(r -> {
        final Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setDaemon(false);
        return thread;
    });

    service.submit(() -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Done: " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    service.shutdownNow();
}
```